# Trigger a function on Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to filter my search results. I got something: http://jsfiddle.net/hzW2a/88/ but it only works once and it's because I've put a constant value in the textbox. So I don't know how to trigger the function again with a new value in the textbox.

The function is this:

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function () {
var x = $('.search2').val();
return $(this).text() === x;
}).closest("tr");


$(".search").click(function() {
        $('tr').not(tableRow).hide();
});
```

But the first function only triggers once (...I guess)

BTW: I'm noob in jQuery and I've been mixing codes from other examples trying to get what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".search").click(function() {
  $('tr').show();

  var tableRow = $("td").filter(function () {
    var x = $('.search2').val();
    return $(this).text().indexOf(x) > -1;
  }).closest("tr");

  $('tr').not(tableRow).hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hzW2a/90/)